# Strange "No instance of constructor matches the argument list" error (Solved)

Tags: c++, constructor, arguments, wrapper

Edit: I had copied the base template for the statisticscompiler class from another solution, and it seems I somehow had ended up editing the original one while including the new one (that hadn't been edited yet) which is what led to the errors. So a tale of caution against copy pasting code into another file with the same name.

I will just post the header files because I think that's what matters here, let me know if otherwise and I can post the cpp. I have one base class that collects statistics from a process, with two derived classes and then a class that let's me use several statistics classes at once

Statistics.h

```
#pragma once
#define STATISTIC_H
#include <vector>
#include "Arrays.h"

class Statistics
{
public:
    Statistics() {}
    virtual void DumpOnePath(MJArray results) = 0;
    virtual std::vector<std::vector<double>> GetResultsSoFar() const = 0;
    virtual Statistics* clone() const = 0;
    virtual ~Statistics() {}
private:
};

class StatisticsMean : public Statistics
{
public:
    StatisticsMean();
    virtual void DumpOnePath(MJArray results) ;
    virtual std::vector<std::vector<double>> GetResultsSoFar() const ;
    virtual Statistics* clone() const;
private:
    MJArray RunningSums;
    unsigned long PathsDone;
};

class StatisticsQuantiles : public Statistics
{
public:
    StatisticsQuantiles(double p_lower_, double p_upper_);
    virtual void DumpOnePath(MJArray results);
    virtual std::vector<std::vector<double>> GetResultsSoFar() const;
    virtual Statistics* clone() const;
private:
    std::vector<MJArray> RunningResults;
    unsigned long PathsDone;
    double p_lower;
    double p_upper;
};
```

StatisticsCompiler.h

```
#pragma once
#define STATISTICS_COMPILER_H
#include "statistics.h"
#include "wrapper.h"
class StatisticsCompiler : public Statistics
{
public:
    StatisticsCompiler(const std::vector <Wrapper<Statistics>>& Inner_);
    virtual Statistics* clone() const;
    virtual void DumpOnePath(MJArray results);
    virtual std::vector<std::vector<double>> GetResultsSoFar() const;
private:
    std::vector <Wrapper<Statistics>> Inner;
};
```

And in my main class I'm trying to do this:

```
StatisticsMean meanGatherer;
StatisticsQuantiles quantileGatherer(p_lower, p_upper);
vector<Wrapper<Statistics>> gathererArray{ meanGatherer, quantileGatherer};
StatisticsCompiler meanAndQuantileGatherer(gathererArray);
```

Which gives an error no the last line complaining that "No instance of constructor matches the argument list. Argument types are:

```
(std::vector<Wrapper<Statistics>, std::allocator<Wrapper<Statistics>>>)."
```

But isn't that exactly what I've defined the constructor to accept? at least the first part, I don't know what

```
std::allocator<Wrapper<Statistics>>
```

means.

Wrapper.h in case needed. It does the memory handling

```
#pragma once
#define WRAPPER_H
template< class T>
class Wrapper
{
public:
    Wrapper()
    {
        DataPtr = 0;
    }
    Wrapper(const T& inner)
    {
        DataPtr = inner.clone();
    }
    ~Wrapper()
    {
        if (DataPtr != 0)
            delete DataPtr;
    }
    Wrapper(const Wrapper<T>& original)
    {
        if (original.DataPtr != 0)
            DataPtr = original.DataPtr->clone();
        else
            DataPtr = 0;
    }
    Wrapper& operator=(const Wrapper<T>& original)
    {
        if (this != &original)
        {
            if (DataPtr != 0) {
                delete DataPtr;
            }
            DataPtr = (original.DataPtr != 0) ? original.DataPtr->clone() : 0;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    T& operator*()
    {
        return *DataPtr;
    }
    const T& operator*() const
    {
        return *DataPtr;
    }
    const T* const operator->() const
    {
        return DataPtr;
    }
    T* operator->()
    {
        return DataPtr;
    }
private:
    T* DataPtr;
};
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Waht is `Wrapper`? In your code there is no conversion from `StatisticsMean` or `StatisticsQuantiles` to `Wrapper<Statistics>` so it is not clear why you expect it to work

Comment: Wrapper.h is a template class that manages the memory handling for the statistics classes. I expected the compiler to do this conversion for me (I'm not sure why, it just has before and I got the wrapper code from a book), I posted the wrapper.h code as well but I don't think it will help much

Comment: This [seems](https://godbolt.org/z/__3okh) to work for me.

Comment: It doesn't look like you made any real changes to the code, right? Very strange. Any wild guess at all why my program seems to complain still?

And thank you a lot for checking that out